# Usage of Coherence (or GUPnP)? to stream A/V?

Tags: python, network-protocols, upnp, coherence-toolkit, gupnp

After looking for some time to a solution for streaming audio/video via uPnP, Coherence seems to be the most promising option: For example: http://coherence.beebits.net/browser/trunk/Coherence/coherence/backends/gstreamer_renderer.py seems to be what would be required to play a file directly to a HDMI TV dongle.

Oddly enough, after installing the Ubuntu coherence package, running `import coherence` in Python terminal doesn't really show anything like this module. Tab completion in bpython shows:

```
>>> coherence.
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│SERVER_ID           Version             platform                           │
│sys                 twisted_version     twisted_web_version                │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

and those submodules seem to just give info about the system. How do I import and use Coherence to stream the desktop, or a video, to a uPnP screen? Is there a basic getting started guide?

**Update**

It looks like GUPnP has ability to link in to Python:

```
>>> from gi.repository import GUPnP
>>> GUPnP.ControlPoint.new()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: new() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)
```

Which is apparently calling the function documented here:
https://developer.gnome.org/gupnp/unstable/GUPnPControlPoint.html

Unfortunately the docs don't have any full examples of how to stream to a video receiver - specifically, how does it initiate sending the video file over the network?

Update: This is the first step I use to detect the device:

```
import socket
import threading
import time

Addr = None;
StartLock = threading.Lock()

def DoUDP():
    global Addr
    global StartLock
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) #Internet, UDP
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
    while 1:
        s.sendto('0:0',('192.168.0.255',63630))
        data,addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        print data
        print 'from', addr
        Addr = addr
        try:
            StartLock.release()
        except:
            pass
        time.sleep(1)
        return

StartLock.acquire()
print 'starting...'
udpthread = threading.Thread(target=DoUDP)
udpthread.start();

#... knowing address of the device... send stuff?
```

Answer (score 4):

About GUPnP on python: it's not extensively used and definitely not documented well enough but it should work. Here's a quick example of listing the available devices on wlan0 network using a GUPnP ControlPoint:

```
from gi.repository import GLib, GUPnP

def device_available (cp, proxy):
   print ("Found " + proxy.get_friendly_name ())

ctx = GUPnP.Context.new (None, "wlan0", 0)
cp = GUPnP.ControlPoint.new (ctx, "upnp:rootdevice")
cp.set_active (True)
cp.connect ("device-proxy-available", device_available)

GLib.MainLoop ().run ()
```

The problem with "streaming to a renderer" is that you actually need two things: the control point that tells the renderer what you want to play, and the mediaserver that serves the actual media when the renderer asks for it -- if these are integrated into one (called the "2-box push model"), the mediaserver part is not quite as complex but it still needs to be done.

One project you may be interested in is dleyna: It is based on GUPnP and tries to make this client side work a little easier. See [Jens' article](http://jensge.org/2013/04/dlna-client-side/) and documentation for [PushHost](https://01.org/dleyna/documentation/renderer-objects). However dleyna is a set of D-Bus services, not a library so you'll have to decide if it fits your purposes.

Alternatively you can of course have a normal mediaserver (like rygel) running and use a control point (like gupnp-av-cp from gupnp-tools) to select the media you want to play and the renderer that should play it.

Comment: Oddly enough, your example shows another computer on the network, but never the Tronsmart device. Do I need to specify a protocol/port first? See my updated question, code I use to see what local IP the device is.

Comment: You don't need to know the IP address beforehand: one of the points of UPnP is that SSDP lets us discover devices. I really don't understand what your script tries to do... I suppose it might try to do the discovery part on its own? That does not seem useful: it's already done by all UPnP stacks (like GUPnP) and getting it right is a lot of work, the script is not even close to being complete.

Comment: gupnp-universal-cp (from gupnp-tools) might be a good way to double-check if the device even is a standard UPnP device. That doesn't get you any closer to being able to do a 2-box push, but at least you'd see if it seems to be a UPnP device or not.